# How to check using jQuery if second or sixth f:selectItem of p:selectManyCheckbox is checked?

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.4 `<p:selectManyCheckbox>`. I would like to know if the user has checked the second or sixth select item.

Here is the relevant code:

```html
<h:form id="signup-form">
    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Export" icon="ui-icon-extlink" onclick="exportChart()"/>  
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="ja"  layout="pageDirection">  
        <f:selectItem id="hola" itemLabel="Importadores." itemValue="1" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Distribuidores nacionales o regionales." itemValue="1" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cadenas de Supermercados." itemValue="1" /> 
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Otros minoristas de venta a cliente final." itemValue="1" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hoteles, restaurantes, cafeterías o similares." itemValue="1" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cliente final particular." itemValue="2" /> 
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cliente final empresas." itemValue="2" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
</h:form>
```

The `exportChart()` function which is executed on click of the command button is as follows:

```html
<script>
    function exportChart() {  
        alert($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('signup-form:ja:hola')).is(':checked'));
    }  
</script>
```

It however always alerts `false`. How can I check if the user has checked the second or sixth select item?

Comment: Why did you give multiple items the same item value? Now you can't uniquely idenfity the checked item in the server side at all. In the client side it's possible, but pretty whacky. If you give all items an unique item value, then you can more easily uniquely identify the item in both client and server side.

Comment: Might be unrelated, but what version of jQuery are you using? (there was a problem I had with `:checked` once....)

Answer (score 2):

The `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` as you've there generates *basically* the following HTML (all jQuery UI fanciness omitted):

```
<input id=​"signup-form:​ja:0" name=​"signup-form:​ja" type=​"checkbox" value=​"1">​
<input id=​"signup-form:​ja:​1" name=​"signup-form:​ja" type=​"checkbox" value=​"1">​
<input id=​"signup-form:​ja:​2" name=​"signup-form:​ja" type=​"checkbox" value=​"1">​
<input id=​"signup-form:​ja:​3" name=​"signup-form:​ja" type=​"checkbox" value=​"1">​
<input id=​"signup-form:​ja:​4" name=​"signup-form:​ja" type=​"checkbox" value=​"1">​
<input id=​"signup-form:​ja:​5" name=​"signup-form:​ja" type=​"checkbox" value=​"2">​
<input id=​"signup-form:​ja:​6" name=​"signup-form:​ja" type=​"checkbox" value=​"2">​
```

So, the following jQuery should do it:

```
if ($("input[name='signup-form:ja']:eq(1)").is(":checked")) {
    alert("The second item is checked");
}

if ($("input[name='signup-form:ja']:eq(5)").is(":checked")) {
    alert("The sixth item is checked");
}
```

Note that the index is zero based.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'd however fix the item values accordingly so that they are all unique, otherwise you would in the server side not know at all which items exactly are been checked — it's the item value which is been submitted to the server side, not the item label. With unique item values, you can in jQuery also more reliably determine the checked values. Basing on the item index is whacky as that's not maintainable (e.g. if you ever need to rearrange or expand the items based on some business requirements, you'd have to fix all your scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Hello i resolved how to check, i did 3 things:

***1-** I put a id to selectManyCheckBox and created inputext type=hidden for each** selectItem.
`

```
                                <p:selectManyCheckbox  id="many1" value="#{cuestionarioController.pd2Opciones}" layout="pageDirection">  
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Centroamerica." itemValue="3" />  
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mexico." itemValue="4" />  
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Estados Unidos/Canada." itemValue="5" /> 
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Brasil." itemValue="5" />  
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sudamérica." itemValue="4" /> 
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Caribe." itemValue="5" /> 
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="España." itemValue="5" /> 
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Otros países europeos." itemValue="6" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="China." itemValue="6" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Otros." itemValue="2" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="La empresa no ha comenzado a exportar de forma regular." itemValue="0" />
                                    <p:ajax listener="#{cuestionarioController.sumarOpciond2}"/>
                                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
                            </p:panelGrid>

                            <p:inputText id="texto1" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali1D2}" /> 
                            <p:inputText id="texto2" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali2D2}" />  
                            <p:inputText id="texto3" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali3D2}" />  
                            <p:inputText id="texto4" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali4D2}" />  
                            <p:inputText id="texto5" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali5D2}" />  
                            <p:inputText id="texto6" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali6D2}" />  
                            <p:inputText id="texto7" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali7D2}" />  
                            <p:inputText id="texto8" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali8D2}" />  
                            <p:inputText id="texto9" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali9D2}" />  
                            <p:inputText id="texto10" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali10D2}" />  
                            <p:inputText id="texto11" type="hidden" value="#{cuestionarioController.pi.vali11D2}" />  

                        </p:outputPanel>`
```

**2- A commandButton that call a function in javascript.**

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Resultado" onclick="validate()"/>
```

3- The function Javascript that i called validate, in this I used the escapeClientId of primefaces what is the reference for his component in jquery. The important thing is the reference, i viewed the code generates basically by primefaces in HTML "formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:0", the fisrt is the form, second a TabView, third the selectManyCheckBox and the last is the location of the selectItem. So when the checkBox is change this set a inputtext

```
function validate() {  
              //de2

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:0')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto1')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto1')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:1')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:text2')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto2')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:2')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto3')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto3')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:3')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto4')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto4')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:4')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto5')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto5')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:5')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto6')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto6')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:6')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto7')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto7')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:7')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto8')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto8')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:8')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto9')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto9')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:9')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto10')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto10')).val("0");
            }

            if($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:many1:10')).is(':checked') == true){ 
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto11')).val("1");
            }else{
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formInternacionalizacion:tabPreg_Inter:texto11')).val("0");
            }

            location.href ="resultadoGraficoMedia.xhtml";
        }
```